# How to set button to scroll to next tableview row?

Tags: ios, swift

So each row has the same button and I want that button to scroll to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

In tableView, you can set each button has different tags(`button.tag`). When you selected it, use tag to decide which row you will scroll to.

Comment: im using custom cell, so each row in the tableview is the same but with different content from parse.

Comment: @gooberboobbutt UITableView has a method that you can get cell index by a cell. You can try it.